# Large number of markers

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on an application utilizing SDK version 1.0.2 that needs to manage 400-500 markers. Generally speaking the performance is very good except when a custom info window is visible.  The large number or markers and custom info window causes the UI to stutter.

I realize the issue is the number of markers and when I reduce the number of markers the issue does not appear.  I have tried to reduce the number of markers by only adding those that are visible during the didChangeCameraPosition callback but I found that adding and removing markers have a bigger performance hit.

Not sure what else I can try and any advice on how to proceed would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried some sort of clustering algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried throttling requests to add markers on didChangeCameraPosition? Maybe only adding a markers when the user had stopped interacting with it for a certain number of milliseconds?

Comment: You should probably re-use your custom infowindow, and just update it. Instead of making a new one for every marker.

Comment: Please, open a issue on their issue tracking tool. This seems to be a common error. I'm facing same problem and is still not solved. @skarE solution doesn't work for me :(

Comment: When filing a issue, if you can include a sample app that shows the problem that will help. Thanks! 
The link to the issue tracker is: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Bug

Answer (score 0):

The new SDK version 1.4.0 released in July 2013 has a new delegate method `mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:` which will be called after the end of a camera movement. So you can possibly shift the marker adding logic to this method instead of  `didChangeCameraPosition` which will be called multiple times during the course of a camera change. This should improve some performance.